# CascadingDropDownList not working with anonymous access

Tags: web-services, asp.net-ajax, cascadingdropdown, anonymous-access

I use a CascadingDropDownList of the AJAXControlToolkit in a ASP.NET MCMS 2002 web application. The CascadingDropDownList works as expected until "Anonymous access" and "Integrated Windows Authentication" flags are both checked (and this is the situation in the production environment) in the Directory Security settings on the website under IIS.

The error I get is:
500 Internal Server Error
No web service found at:

If I uncheck the anonymous access or the windows authentication everything is ok.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying:

ServicePath="~/IB20/Services/RegioniProvinceService.asmx"

in:

ServicePath="http:///Services/RegioniProvinceService.asmx"

solved the issue.

It seems that having "Anonymous access" and "Integrated authentication" both checked, brokes the functionality if the ServicePath of the CascadingDropDownList is file-system oriented.